# Tools for Apache Cordova - Deploy Windows Phone (Universal) in "Device" is missing

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

i miss the selection for the deployment of a windows phone (universal) app to a physical device. The silverlight windows phone version can be deployed to a device. The MSDN article say that the item "device" must be avaliable in dropdown. What can i do?

I use Visual Studio 2015 RC.

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Possible solution 1]

This kind of issue usually is caused by something wrong in your .suo file.

I think if you create a new project, the "Device" option will show up. If it doesn't, that could not be solved by following steps.

To solve this issue, let's try to delete the user option file.

1. Open the solution folder
2. Enable hidden items in the file explorer, you will see a hidden folder .vs shows up.
3. Delete the .vs folder and open your solution in VS again. That will help to recreate the user specific options and config.

[**Upate 20150612**]

I suddenly realized what is wrong. Your screenshort gave me a hint- you are not using en-us as your language, seems it is de-DE. And I found there is no PhoneDevice81 config file for this language. So **as a workaround**, change the language setting to English may help. I am currently installing additional language pack for test, will update more possible workarounds later if have.

So here is what I found:

The debugger list is defined in the following file:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Phone81Launch.targets"

The interest line in that file is:

```
<PropertyPageSchema Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)$(LangName)\PhoneEmulator81Wvga4512.xaml">
```

It does exist in en-US folder. Then I tried to find out which language uses "Zoll" as inch in English. Then I found it might be DE(German right?).

So go into the de-DE folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\de-DE", I found there is no PhoneDevice81 exist. More interesting thing is only en-us folder has the PhoneDevice81 windows markup file.

So I guess this could be a by-design issue that only en-us is supported for RC. But I will definitely report this to the VS team.

[**More workaround**]

I just installed the language package and changed language setting:
in VS->Tools->Options->Environment->International settings->change the language->restart VS.

Then I copied the PhoneDevice81 markup file from en-us folder to de-DE folder, and created a new blank cordova app. Then I am able to see the "Device" option and able to debug on the device.

But please note I am still not sure why it doesn't exist by default, so I cannot say what are the potential issues for this workaround.

Comment: Hi, i create a new project but the device option will not appear :(

Comment: Hella Alan, you again :P I installed the engliish languagepack for VS and switch to it. After that i had the option "device" for windows phone (universal). Thank you. Looks like MS forget only people in other countries ;)